# Simple solution to write Python web app with mod_fcgid?

Tags: python, mod-fcgid

On a shared Apache server that has mod_fcgid (not mod_wsgi), I'd like to write simple web apps in Python instead of using PHP.

I've done a lot of reading and testing, but no solution worked because of the restrictions of a shared server ("pip: command not found", "[me] is not in the sudoers file", "easy_install [app]: unable to open /usr/local/include/python2.6/pyconfig.h", etc.)

Is mod_fcgid just not the right solution to write Python apps on a shared server so am losing my time and should just move to a hoster that supports Python from the start?

Thank you.

Comment: There's lots of answers on google: http://www.electricmonk.nl/docs/apache_fastcgi_python/apache_fastcgi_python.html . What are you trying to install with pip?

Comment: Thanks for the link. I read it before, but it's from 2009, doesn't mention mod_fcgid, and assumes the user has total access to the server. I guess I'm looking at a way to run non-WSGI Python apps so there's a direct link between mod_fcgid and the Python script.

Comment: I was trying to install Flup, since it's apparently the most used FastCGI server to handle WSGI scripts.

Comment: If you can't install any software, you might just have to fallback to using cgi. Have you tried asking your host to allow mod_wsgi?

Comment: Yes I did. CGI works but it's a bit slow. If all else fails, I'll just move to another hoster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Python can use any package/module it finds in `sys.path`/`$PYTHONPATH`.](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path) Simply install to an alternate location and make sure it's specified in those.

Comment: You can use virtualenv to help with organizing your local python modules.  If you are looking for examples, you can use http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/deploying/fastcgi/ as another example of using flup to host a WSGI app via apache + fastcgi.